# Can I wake up my Mac wirelessly over the internet?

Tags: ipad, wifi, sleep-wake

I am a university student who leaves his Macbook Pro at home and uses an iPad in lectures.

I thought it'd be great if I was able to wake my Mac back at home if I needed to remote control it using TeamViewer from my iPad.

My Macbook is running Mountain Lion (Latest) and is connected Wirelessly to a Virgin Superhub.

Is it possible to set it to boot from the university from my iPad so I can remote control it? If so, how do I set this up?

Comment: some vaguenesses: Do you want to boot ór to wake up the mac? What kind of MacBook do you have?

Answer (score 1):

OSX has a feature called [Wake on Demand](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774) (Apple's version of [Wake on Lan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)) which does work over Wifi but:

> Wake on Demand requires an Apple AirPort Base Station or Time Capsule
>   with firmware 7.4.2 or later installed. To use Wake on Demand
>   wirelessly with a WPA or WPA2 network, the AirPort base station or
>   Time Capsule must be hosting the network.

Instead you can use the [traditional Wake on Lan](http://lifehacker.com/348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake+on+lan), however this requires an ethernet connection (AFAIK)...

Comment: okay, wake on demand is on, but which app (and further settings) on your iPhone/iPad can you use to connect with your mac, and still have the mac still password-protected when waking?

Answer (score 0):

You need *something* that can send the appropriate network packet to wake up the machine.  Apples routers (I have a Time Capsule) can proxy Bonjour-announced services while the machine is sleeping and can wake up the machine when the proxied service is accessed.  Apple also has a "Back to my Mac" feature, which I do not know if the iPad supports.

I do not think you can do what you want with your combination of sleeping devices and router hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps iOS app [Knock](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/knock-unlock-your-mac-without/id692929970?mt=8) or [Scany](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scany-network-scanner/id328077901?mt=8) can make this happen.
Knock requires Bluetooth 4, Scany requires quite some tech-knowhow.

Unfortunately my mac is too old and my knowhow too restricted to check it.
(I like to be able to do this as well).